# .webm video autoplay in iphone and tablets

Tags: iphone, iframe, video, webm

I have created this webpage with this video using iframe.

http://mediafactory.gr/webm/

If someone clicks the link, he will see the video immediately with no placeholder.

How can I do this for iphones and tablets also? Right now if you open the link using iphone or tablets the site will ask for an application to open the video.

I have used this code.

```
<iframe src="http://mediafactory.gr/wp-content/e-card/bahagram/eCard.webm" width="1024" height="150"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOS doesn't support [Webm](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webm). But I read a [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/forum/#!topic/webm-discuss/beWIR7UEuyg) and it says that it will propose a vlc:// url handler that will enable to launch vlc to play an http (webm or anythin) stream directly in VLC in Safari. Check it out and let me know.

Comment: I did not find a convenient solution so i redirected the page "If mobile" to a link with an mp4 video instead. It does the job for now. Thank you for answering thoug! :)